# Table inner join itself

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a table with 3 columns (code, state, date), it records the history of a code state, each code may have changed state multiple times.

I want to show the last state of each code what I did was like this

```
SELECT code,MAX(date), .... 
FROM table 
GROUP BY code.
```

I don't know what to put exactly to get the state. I tried to just put state so it gets the state corresponding to the combination of `code,max(date)` but it gives me the error of not in aggregate function.

thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You can use a window function to do this or a sub query `select max(date), code ...  group by code ` and then join.

Comment: but when I join I get multiple records per code I used an inner join.

Comment: Hopefully my answer covers your questions :P

Comment: @xQbert: it does thank you, I will look at the window function more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you have data such as

```
CODE  State  Date
1     IL     1/1/2016
1     IA     1/1/2017
1     AL     1/1/2015
```

and you want to see in your results

```
1 IA 1/1/2017
```

using a window function and a common table expression (with): we assign a row number to each code based on the date in descending order and return only the first row for each.

```
With CTE AS (SELECT code
           , date
           , state
           , Row_number() over (partition by code order by date desc) RN
             FROM table )
SELECT Code, Date, State 
FROM CTE 
WHERE RN =1
```

Using a subquery: (we get the max date for each code and then join back to the base set to limit the rows returned.

```
SELECT A.code, A.date, A.state
FROM table  A
INNER JOIN (SELECT max(date) mdate, code 
            FROM table 
            GROUP BY code) B
 on A.Code = B.Code
and A.Date = B.MDate
```

The later query was used when/if window functions are not available.  The modern method of solving your question is using the first approach.

In essence what the 1st query does is assign the # 1 to x for each code based on the date descending.  So the max date gets a RN of 1 for each code.  Thus when we say where RN = 1 we only return codes/states/records having max dates for the code in question.  We use a `with` statement because we need the RN to materialize (actually get generated in memory) so that we can then limit by it in the second part of the `with` (common table expression) query.

Comment: You get me, this is what I want to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing an aggregate, like `MAX()`, then all other non-aggregate columns that are in your select, need to also be in your `GROUP BY`.  That's why you're getting the error when you add `state` to only the select.  If you add it to the select and group by it, you'll get your results:

```
SELECT State, Code, MAX(Date)
FROM table
GROUP BY State, Code
```

Comment: but in this case if I have say code 1 with state 1 and 2 they will be two times code 1 what I need is a unique code with the corresponding state of the max(date) the last state of every code.

Comment: @Houss_gc I read your question too fast, check xQbert's answer :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to user inner join like you mention in your post Inner join back to itself with matching `code` and `date`

```
SELECT * 
FROM table t1
INNER JOIN  (SELECT code,MAX(date)
             FROM table 
             GROUP BY code) codeWithLatestDate ON t1.code = codeWithLatestDate.code AND t1.date = codeWithLatestDate.dat3
```

However I would suggest add `state` to your `GROUP BY` clause and `SELECT` cluase

```
SELECT code,MAX(date),state
FROM table 
GROUP BY code, state
```

Answer (score 1):

Youn can do it with a join to itself

```
SELECT State,Code,Date
FROM table t
JOIN (
SELECT  Code, MAX(Date) as Date
FROM table
GROUP BY  Code) t1 on t1.Code= t.Code and t.Date=t1.Date
```